# Hyperledger Fabric Private Data Collection

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am running BYFN(Default) as a network  and here is my `chaincode` used for test purpose 
[Chaincode link](https://hastebin.com/ujojuseney.cs) My collection config is [Config File Link](https://hastebin.com/ibijowolaj.json) .
Now Let me explain the issue. When i Query from authorized peer means any of peer of ORG1 its gives me correct result

```
{
  "public_data": {
    "docType": "car",
    "name": "Honda Amaze",
    "color": "blue",
    "size": 35,
    "owner": "tom"
  },
  "privatedata": {
    "docType": "car",
    "name": "Honda Amaze",
    "owner_address": "Vill anyari url alinagar Moradabad"
  }
}
```

But when I query from unauthorized peer means any peer of organization 2 then inspite of error message that we can't access data. I am getting response as

```
{
  "public_data": {
    "docType": "car",
    "name": "Honda Amaze",
    "color": "blue",
    "size": 35,
    "owner": "tom"
  },
  "privatedata": {
    "docType": "",
    "name": "",
    "owner_address": ""
  }
}
```

You can see that private data is not there .
If i run marbels private data exmple it gives me error from unauthorized peer

> {"Error":"Failed to get private details for marble1: GET_STATE failed:
>   transaction ID:
>   b04adebbf165ddc90b4ab897171e1daa7d360079ac18e65fa15d84ddfebfae90:
>   Private data matching public hash version is not available. Public
>   hash version = &version.Height{BlockNum:0x6, TxNum:0x0}, Private data
>   version = (*version.Height)(nil)"}"

No `Marbels` private example they are not getting data from simple ledger But in my `chaincode` am getting data from normal ledger and private data both.

Any help Much appereciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got a issue that in my chaincode am not returning error if chaincode produce an error .But If i have to fetch both type of data(Simple Ledger & Private Data) in a single transaction then which approach i should follow. ?

Comment: You can work with both regular data and private data within the same transaction.

Answer (score 2):

I expect the difference is simply related to your error handling code in your chaincode.  You need to handle the error returned by GetPrivateData().

Comment: Thanks @Dave .We accept the issue .Issue was related to chaincode error handling

Answer (score 0):

This error I also faced but for me it was occurring because I added the peer details of unauthorized peer.